# Cross-domain @font-face support

Tags: css, apache, font-face

I am having trouble figuring out a way to support @font-face having the font hosted on a different server/domain than mine. The way our server works - I have NO access to our server configuration files. I can only access a CSS/JS files, and am unable to then load font files to our server (I know...).

Ideally, I would like to reference the font(s) on the site I am branding from (I replicate a website design onto our product so that they can integrate it into their site relatively seamlessly). Reading through the following article:

http://www.unseenrevolution.com/solution-firefox-font-face-cross-domain-problem/

would I be able to utilize a similar method if I have the owner of the other domain add our domain to their HTACCESS file? I apologize if the question seems useless, but I am having trouble understanding how this works clearly - and I don't want to recommend a solution that won't work anyway.

Any help?

Comment: Even if you can you would still need your server with the correct configuration...unless you can do Google Web Fonts.

Comment: Ah. Could you explain a little more in depth? Yeah, we push for Google fonts when we can - but they have already purchased the one they are using.